# How to write out this format of euclidean algroithm

Tags: math-mode

[image]

How to write out this format of euclidean algorithm

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the many possible routes you can take is this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0, 0, 1}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{0.937, 0.568, 0}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
52 & : & \color{blue}{36} & = &  1 &     &   &   &   & \: \: \: \: \: \:  \: \: \: \: \: \: \text{remainder} \left( {\color{orange}{16}} \right) \\
   &   & \color{blue}{36} & : & \color{orange}{16} & =   & 1 &   &   & \: \: \: \: \: \:  \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \text{remainder} \left( {\color{blue}{4}} \right)\\
   &   &    &   & \color{orange}{16} & : & \color{blue}{\text{\circled{4}}} & = & 4 & \: \: \: \: \: \:  \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \:  \text{remainder} \left( {\text{\textbf{0}}} \right)\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]